# Androidstudio: cheking internet, while device connected to slow internet it freeze

Tags: android, android-studio, connection

I am trying to check internet connection in androidstudio.
But all codes that I found from websites are not usefull for me. Cause Codes I found from websites, is working when there is no connection. But when device connected to internet that is slow, it freezs or after a long time it finish its cheking. So is there anywayto set time limit to cheking connection. Is anybody got any clue? Thanks.

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {

    try {
        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); //You can replace it with your name
        return !ipAddr.equals("");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

I tried this but it doesnt working, my program freezed again.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Where are you calling this?

Comment: Are you calling it in the UI thread?

Comment: No, I call it as function.

Comment: Show the method call code too.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague but try this

```
private boolean isConnectedToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

It checks all internet connections; wireless, cable, data from ISP

Comment: Yes it checks but when device connected to slow internet it takes too long. Is there any way to set time out or something like that?

Comment: usually if you are use retrofit or okhttp, it handles the timeout and retries if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
// NETWORK AND CONNECTIVITY CHECK METHOD
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable (Context context) {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo netowrkInfo = connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return netowrkInfo != null && netowrkInfo.isConnected();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

may it helps...